# Error asking ChatGPT: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: node.js

Using google vision API, react, and node.js, I created a program that turns on the camera when you press the button and recognizes the words in it when you take a picture with the camera. For example, if a card is captured by the camera and the word ‘Black Village Card’ is written on it, that part is displayed in the react web app. Now, I want to go one step further and create a program where, when the react app recognizes the word 'black village card', the user enters the word 'black village card' in the chatgpt search box through chatgptapi and chatgpt shows the user the answer to the input. I'll share the code I've created so far. The problem that arises when you get to this point is that chatgpt does not display the correct answer. It keeps saying ‘Error getting response from ChatGPT’. When I looked at this part in the terminal, Error asking ChatGPT: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400 appeared.
I'll show you my entire code and if there are any errors please let me know.

frontend

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Suspense } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function DetectedTextComponent({ base64Image }) {
  const [detectedText, setDetectedText] = useState("");
  const [gptResponse, setGptResponse] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const detectText = async () => {
      if (!base64Image) return;
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:3001/api/detect-text",
          { image: base64Image }
        );
        setDetectedText(response.data.text || "");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Text detection failed:", error);
        setDetectedText(`Error: ${error.message}`);
      }
    };
    detectText();
  }, [base64Image]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getGptResponse = async () => {
      if (!detectedText) return;
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:3001/api/ask-chatgpt",
          { question: detectedText }
        );
        setGptResponse(response.data.answer || "");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error asking ChatGPT:", error);
        setGptResponse("Error getting response from ChatGPT");
      }
    };
    getGptResponse();
  }, [detectedText]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Detected Text: {detectedText}</p>
      <p>ChatGPT Response: {gptResponse}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [videoStream, setVideoStream] = useState(null);
  const [capturedImage, setCapturedImage] = useState(null);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    content: "",
    age: "1st grade",
  });
  const [contentData, setContentData] = useState([]);
  const [view, setView] = useState("initialView");
  const [detectedText, setDetectedText] = useState("");
  const [editingIndex, setEditingIndex] = useState(null);
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

  const startCamera = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        console.log("Camera accessed successfully.");
        setView("cameraView");
        setVideoStream(stream);
        let video = document.getElementById("videoStream");
        video.srcObject = stream;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error accessing camera: ", err);
      });
  };

  const detectTextFromImage = async (base64Image) => {
    try {
      console.log("Sending image for text detection...");
      const response = await fetch("/api/detect-text", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ image: base64Image }),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.error) {
        throw new Error(data.error);
      }
      return data.text;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Text detection failed:", error);
      return `Error: ${error.message}`;
    }
  };

  const captureImage = async () => {
    let video = document.getElementById("videoStream");
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    setCapturedImage(imgData);
    try {
      const detectedTextFromImage = await detectTextFromImage(imgData);
      setDetectedText(detectedTextFromImage);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Text detection failed:", error);
      setDetectedText("Error detecting text");
    }
    setView("previewView");
    setShowPopup(true);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  };

  const handleSubmitContent = () => {
    if (typeof editingIndex === "number") {
      let updatedContentData = [...contentData];
      updatedContentData[editingIndex] = formData;
      setContentData(updatedContentData);
      setEditingIndex(null);
    } else {
      setContentData([...contentData, formData]);
    }
    setFormData({
      title: "",
      content: "",
      age: "1st grade",
    });
    setView("initialView");
  };

  const deleteContent = (index) => {
    const updatedData = [...contentData];
    updatedData.splice(index, 1);
    setContentData(updatedData);
  };

  const editContent = (index) => {
    setFormData(contentData[index]);
    setEditingIndex(index);
    setView("editView");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="centered">
        {view === "initialView" && (
          <>
            <p>보드게임 개인판을 준비해주세요</p>
            <p>준비가 다 되었다면 아래 카메라 버튼을 눌러주세요</p>
            <button onClick={startCamera} className="cameraButton">
               카메라 켜기
            </button>
            {contentData.map((content, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="savedContent">
                <h1>{content.title}</h1>
                <p>{content.content}</p>
                <p>Age: {content.age}</p>
                <button onClick={() => editContent(index)}>수정</button>
                <button onClick={() => deleteContent(index)}>삭제</button>
              </div>
            ))}
          </>
        )}

        {view === "cameraView" && (
          <>
            <video id="videoStream" autoPlay={true} muted={true}></video>
            <button onClick={captureImage} className="cameraButton">
               사진 찍기
            </button>
          </>
        )}

        {view === "previewView" && (
          <>
            <img src={capturedImage} alt="Captured" />
            <div>
              <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading detected text...</div>}>
                <DetectedTextComponent base64Image={capturedImage} />
              </Suspense>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Title"
                name="title"
                value={formData.title}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
              <textarea
                placeholder="Content"
                name="content"
                value={formData.content}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              ></textarea>
              <select
                name="age"
                value={formData.age}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              >
                <option value="1st grade">1학년</option>
                <option value="2nd grade">2학년</option>
                <option value="3rd grade">3학년</option>
              </select>
              <button onClick={handleSubmitContent}>저장</button>
            </form>
          </>
        )}

        {view === "editView" && (
          <>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Title"
                name="title"
                value={formData.title}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
              <textarea
                placeholder="Content"
                name="content"
                value={formData.content}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              ></textarea>
              <select
                name="age"
                value={formData.age}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              >
                <option value="1st grade">1학년</option>
                <option value="2nd grade">2학년</option>
                <option value="3rd grade">3학년</option>
              </select>
              <button onClick={handleSubmitContent}>수정 완료</button>
            </form>
          </>
        )}

        {showPopup && (
          <div className="popup">
            <h1>Detected Text</h1>
            <p>{detectedText ? detectedText : "No text detected"}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setShowPopup(false)}>Close</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

backend

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const vision = require("@google-cloud/vision");
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require("axios");
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

const endpoint = process.env.CHATGPT_ENDPOINT;
axios
  .post(endpoint, "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions")
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error asking ChatGPT:", error);
  });

const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({
  projectId: process.env.GCP_PROJECT_ID,
  keyFilename: process.env.GCP_KEY_FILENAME,
});
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "10mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/api/detect-text", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("Received image for text detection.");
    if (!req.body.image || typeof req.body.image !== "string") {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid image data" });
    }
    const image = req.body.image?.split(",")[1];
    if (!image) return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid image format" });

    const [result] = await client.textDetection({ image: { content: image } });
    const text = result.textAnnotations[0]?.description.trim() || "";
    res.json({ text });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error detecting text:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

app.post("/api/ask-chatgpt", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const question = req.body.question || "";
    const response = await axios.post(
      process.env.CHATGPT_ENDPOINT,
      {
        engine: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        prompt: question,
        max_tokens: 50,
        temperature: 0.2,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.CHATGPT_API_KEY}`,
        },
      }
    );
    res.json({ answer: response.data.answer });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error asking ChatGPT:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Error asking ChatGPT" });
  }
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).json({ error: "Something broke!" });
});

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`)
);
```

AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400 appeared.